# How to add user upload files to git when the node is pulished?

Tags: 7, files, version-control

my requirements is:

- some users are adding application file drupal system adding node.
- initially that node is in unpublished state. Once the admin is publishing the node that uploaded file need to be pushed to into github repo.
- If there any module available for git interaction Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure you want to store user-generated content in Git?  If you need to delete abusive/inappropriate content later, this could make a mess of your repository.

Comment: I want to upload a zip file to git which was upload by use and verified by admin

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the [Version control api](https://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol)

> Version Control API is an engine for Drupal integration with a variety
>   of version control systems. The focus is primarily on working with
>   canonical, server-side repositories. It provides basic tools that
>   allow for things like history listings, commit access controls,
>   triggered actions when new code comes in, and direct on-disk
>   repository management.
>
> This module is a core engine and does nothing on its own without a
>   "backend" module that provides integration with a specific VCS (e.g.
>   git, bzr, svn). This module provides a consistent base interface (UI
>   and API) for interacting with all the different backends.

You will also need the [version control git backend](https://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol_git) as the module does not work on it's own

> This module provides an implementation of the Version Control API that
>   makes it possible to use the Git version control system. It can
>   retrieve commit information by parsing commit logs.
>
> The Git backend depends on the Version Control API module. It also
>   requires Git >=1.7.2 to be installed on the server.

Comment: through this module can we able to commit some files to repo and this module support UI or it support API.